# Spring web Dependency Injection(IOC) and the ServletContextListener

Tags: spring, web-applications, initialization, startup

I have code which is structured as Spring beans and dependencies among them. This is only a small part of the code since the rest is *'legacy'* code.

At this point in time I would like to perform an action on one of these beans in an existing *'legacy'* class that extends `javax.servlet.ServletContextListener`. This class initializes the application and its code is invoked only once.

What is my best course of action?

Thanks!

Answer (score 4):

You can obtain the Spring Context this way:

`WebApplicationContext ctx = WebApplicationContextUtils.getRequiredWebApplicationContext(servletContextEvent.getSevletContext())`

Then you can call ctx.getBean("name"); (and some more - check the javadocs of WebApplicationContext, and its parents)

Answer (score 3):

There's not really any point in a Spring bean extending `ServletContextListener`, since the beans don't listen to the servlet context. If you want to use beans that are initialized and destroyed along with the application, then there are many ways to do this in Spring. See [this part](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/2.5.x/reference/beans.html#beans-factory-lifecycle) of the docs.